# Is Golarion's map covered by the OGL?

Tags: ogl, golarion

Is the world of golarion considered to be covered in the ogl? By which I mean if I was creating a world using golarion for the base map would I infringe any copyrights?

The reason I ask is my dm and I want to enter our world and story to the rpm superstar contest and weren't sure if we could use our current map "golarion base no names reused" or if we have to create one.

Comment: What's an 'rpm superstar contest'?

Comment: If you mean Paizo's RPG Superstar contest, not only do they not have that any more, it has its own rules about what is submitted when and world maps are never part of it.

Answer (score 3):

[As per the Open Game License of Pathfinder](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/openGameLicense.html):

> Product Identity: The following items are hereby identified as Product Identity, as defined in the Open Game License 1.0a, Section 1(e), and **are not Open Content**: All trademarks, registered trademarks, proper names (characters, deities, etc.), dialogue, plots, storylines, **locations**, characters, artworks, and trade dress. (Elements that have previously been designated as Open Game Content are not included in this declaration.)
>
> Open Content: Except for material designated as Product Identity (see above), the game mechanics of this Paizo Publishing game product are Open Game Content, as defined in the Open Game License version 1.0a Section 1(d). No portion of this work other than the material designated as Open Game Content may be reproduced in any form without written permission.

Short answer: no deal. Golarion is not OGL. Mechanics of Pathfinder RPG are.

Answer (score 2):

No. None of Paizo's game setting/"fluff" is covered by the OGL.  It is all Product Identity per the actual open game content declarations in the various works.  On d20pfsrd, even various prestige class and feat names are redacted to take out PI (e.g. "Champion of Irori" is "Champion of the Enlightened." The Golarion map is specifically not included in any OGC statement so it is copyrighted material like any other.

So the answer to the question you asked is "no."  You didn't ask about your actual goal, however, to which the answer is "maybe."

Paizo has a Community Use License (http://paizo.com/paizo/about/communityuse) that allows use of their PI in some cases (on fan sites mostly).  Since you included no information about your end goal (publishing?  Fan site?) I have no way of validating if it fits the license, but you can go read it and determine that for yourself.

See also [What exactly does Paizo consider Product Identity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34814/what-exactly-does-paizo-consider-product-identity)