# How do I publish content for Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, publishing, ogl

I have created a reference document for Pathfinder that I am interested in getting published. I have no clue about how to get this done. I can find the OGL rules and whatnot, but no advice on how to actual get it published. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: The same way you publish anything. What part of publishing are you stuck on? Is this for print or digital publishing?

Comment: Sounds like something you can best get the answer from paizo...

Comment: See also http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26826/what-content-can-i-reproduce-from-pathfinder?rq=1, but more importantly please explain more about what you've created and how you want to publish it.